# php passing variable to label

Tags: php, html, label

I have a function that passes a variable to the "label" tag.  For some reason, it just won't display the variable in the "label" tag.  Here's my code:

```
function radioButton($id, $name, $value, $txt){
   $str = "";
   $str .= '
      <input type="radio" id=$id name=$name value=$value checked>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for=$id> <?php echo $txt; ?></label>
   ';
   return $str;
}

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <?php echo radioButton("MyID", "MyName", "MyValue", "Do Nothing"); ?>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

The radio button is display but not the variable in the "label" tag.  I tried wrapping my variable with the php tag as someone on the internet suggested but it gives me a blank.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1119369/Pass-PHP-variable-value-into-HTML-label

Is this even possible??  To pass a variable to an html label tag in php??

Comment: You need to wrap your variables with quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code:

- The string needs to be declared with quotes around it, not single quotes. This allows easier string concatenation. ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double))

  - Note: If you don't want to this, you can concatenate like this: `$str = '<div>' + $variable + '</div>'` ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single))
- Wrap your variables with single quotes (When string is defined with double quotes, if it's not, wrap variables with double quotes)
- You don't need to open your PHP tags when already in PHP.

This code fixes your issues:

```
function radioButton($id, $name, $value, $txt){
   $str = "
      <input type='radio' id='$id' name='$name' value='$value' checked>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for='$id'>$txt</label>
   ";
   return $str;
}
```

---

Some other problems you should consider fixing:

It's generally frowned upon to have HTML markup inside of PHP, but if you must do this, it's usually better to use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) markup, because it looks cleaner, and allows you to do easy string concatenation but also allows you to use double quotes inside the string itself (without escaping them)

```
function radioButton($id, $name, $value, $txt){
   $str = <<<RADIOBUTTON
        <input type="radio" id="$id" name="$name" value="$value" checked>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="$id">$txt</label>
RADIOBUTTON;
//note, the line before this can't have any whitespace before it.
   return $str;
}
```

Comment: I think I've lost half of my hair cause of this problem and it turns out to be something so simple.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tran If an answer has helped you, be sure to click the check button to the left of the answer. This will gain you and the answerer a little bit of reputation for their troubles.